# Openerp: How to disable a side menu(More) in form view while using ir.actions.server

Tags: menu, hide, odoo

I want to disable a menu from "More" options in form view while using action type "ir.actions.server".
How can i make it possible?

In case of action type "ir.actions.act_window" we can do it by multi = True. Is there any equivalent attribute or something exists for this?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As siddharth jambukiya said, we can use a web module to do his. But there is an another method that can be done from python. If you look at the result of the function **field_view_get** of the model to which the server action belong, you an see that there is a key called "**toolbar**" in the fields_view_get result. This key contains all the details regarding the action in the "**Print**" and "**More**" dropdown in web client. So if you remove the server action from here, that server action wont be listed in the "More" dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any Menu from "More" using web client. you need to implement web module to remove option from More menu. i think no other alternative attribute exists in openerp.